# Software updater stops not sure what to do

Tags: software-updater

I'm updating Ubuntu 12.10.  Its installing updates and stops at displaying a changelog.  I'm not sure how to get it to proceed through the install.  It stops showing (END) at the end of the log.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot or copy-paste of the output?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `sudo apt-get update` in terminal? You can upload it in paste.ubuntu.com and link it here.